# I need to get the max value from an SQL query and save it to a variable

Tags: list, sql-server-ce, vb.net-2010

This is what I have.

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 10, 4) AS serial FROM main1 WHERE (SUBSTRING(column, 1, 3) = 'CAR')", cnx)
If cnx.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnx.Open()
Dim SerialStr As String
Dim SerialList As New List(Of Integer)
Using sdr As SqlCeDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While sdr.Read()
        SerialList.Add(sdr.GetInt32(sdr.GetOrdinal("serial"))) 'I got this from a forum, not sure if it is what I need
    End While
    SerialStr = SerialList.Item(SerialList.Count).ToString
End Using
```

The column where I'm trying to get the data from is a primary key and this is the format:

> CAR2014-S0001
>
> CAR2014-S0007
>
> PAR2014-S0001
>
> CAR2014-S0004
>
> PAR2014-S0002

etc.

As you can see, they're not in order. I need to get the last four digits of each number from the query, order them, get the last one and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT max(right(column, 4)) AS serial FROM main1 WHERE (SUBSTRING(column, 1, 3) = 'CAR')", cnx)
If cnx.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnx.Open()
Dim SerialStr As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```